# Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

Tags: next.js13

i have a problem here ...

can anyone help me here ...

**1 of 1 unhandled error
Next.js is up to date

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

Source
useRouter
node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js (146:14)
src\app\component\header\Index.tsx (14:26) @ useRouter

12 |
13 |

> 14 |   const router = useRouter()
> |                          ^
> 15 |
> 16 |   const [widthPage, setWidthPage] = useState<number>()
> 17 |**

already try put in my code import { useRouter } from "next/navigation" but not work as well !

https://github.com/artursantana/Portfolio-React

i have many links in this page and all it work only one not work i dont know why!